# Basic Oculus Leaderboards.GetEntries API usage throws errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

Trying to do a simple call to the leader board API fails. I even tried copy and pasting some of the example code for the documentation but they also all fail with the same error. Below is the most simple version I could come up with and it also fails. My Oculus developer settings are set up in unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Oculus.Platform;
using Oculus.Platform.Models;

public class leaderBoard : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        Leaderboards.GetEntries("POC-Score", 10, LeaderboardFilterType.None, LeaderboardStartAt.Top).OnComplete(GetEntriesCallback);
    }

    void GetEntriesCallback(Message<LeaderboardEntryList> msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("-----");
        Debug.Log(msg.Data);
        Debug.Log("-----");
    }
}
```

And I get the following error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object leaderBoard.Start () (at Assets/leaderBoard.cs:10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `Leaderboards.GetEntries`, you must initialize the SDK using the App ID then do an entitlement check. If that passes, you can then call the `Leaderboards.GetEntries` function. Let's say that your App ID is *857362746724*, initialize it as:

```
Core.Initialize("857362746724");
```

Now, do an entitlement check. If successful, call the `Leaderboards.GetEntries` function:

```
void checkEntitlement()
{
    Entitlements.IsUserEntitledToApplication().OnComplete(
    (Message msg) =>
    {
        if (msg.IsError)
        {
            // User is NOT entitled.
            Debug.Log("Error: User not entitled");
        } else 
        {
            // User IS entitled
            Debug.Log("Success: User entitled");
            checkEntry();
        }
    }
);
}

void checkEntry()
{
    Leaderboards.GetEntries("POC-Score", 10, LeaderboardFilterType.None, LeaderboardStartAt.Top).OnComplete(GetEntriesCallback);
}

void GetEntriesCallback(Message<LeaderboardEntryList> msg)
{
    Debug.Log("-----");
    Debug.Log(msg.Data);
    Debug.Log("-----");
}
```

With the Start function, it should look like something below:

```
void Start()
{
    Core.Initialize("857362746724");
    checkEntitlement();
}
```